# Why is indexOf not working in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, indexof

This function executes during the forms onSubmit, and works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE. I suspect it's indexOf, but I cannot seem to find a way to get it to work.

```
function checkSuburbMatch(e) {

var theSuburb = document.getElementById('suburb').value;
var thePostcode = document.getElementById('postcode').value;

var arrayNeedle = theSuburb + " (" + thePostcode + ")";

if(suburbs.indexOf(arrayNeedle) != -1) {
    alert("Suburb and Postcode match!");
    return false;
} else {
    alert("Suburb and Postcode do not match!");
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: What does variable "suburbs" contain?

Comment: It's an array of strings going along the lines of "suburbName (postCode)"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't indexOf work on an array IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8). See also: [How to fix Array indexOf() in JavaScript for IE browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/), [Array indexOf implementation for Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868696)

Comment: For a thorough explanation of the issue as well as a work around not only for indexOf but the other missing array functions in IE check out the StackOverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc

Comment: FWIW I have a Dev environment where it works with IE11, but when I promoted to my Test environment it stopped working?!?! So it's like IE has a half-baked implementation out there somewhere

Answer (score 18):

IE simply doesn't have this method on [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), you can add it yourself though, [from MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

This adds `.indexOf()` if it's missing (at this point that means you're in IE<9) then you can use it.  As for why even IE8 doesn't have this already? I can't help you there...

Comment: This didn't seem to work, and made it stop working in Firefox too. Does this need to be placed after the function is called or at the start of the script?

Comment: @David: It needs to be declared before it is called.

Answer (score 10):

If you are already using jQuery in your project you can use   $.inArray()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score 0):

indexOf() on MSIE 11 and others it doesn't like non-string variables. On suburbs add .toString() and it should fix it.

Answer (score -1):

this function is bad when using associative arrays.

if you put that function in your code and do this

```
var a = new Array();

a["one"] = "1";

for(var i in a){

   alert(i)

}
```

You get 0, `indexOf`  which means you inserted `indexOf` as a key to every array you create

but the array should only have one key and that is "one"

use jQuery!

-Mekias